# Gnu screen - how do I move focus to a region by number?

Tags: screen, gnu

`:focus` moves focus relative to the current window, and is based on screen geometry - `:focus top` switches focus to the window touching to top left of my viewport, not to the first window number. Close but not quite.

`:select` switches the current regions window to the specified window number. So focus doesn't move.

Nothing else [in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) appears promising.

This isn't critical; I'm just trying to do to write config files in a way that I later find intuitive to read. I would like to set my layout via splits all at once, and then move to each window explicitly by number and then customize (eg `:title`) explicitly. This would be easier to read than my current config files, which split / `: focus next` / customize / repeat. It works, but I can't later look at these files and easily figure out what's happening. And as to the question "what would such a command do, when multiple regions display the same window?" I assume it'd be easy enough to cycle between them.